# How can I find hotels in a given area that rent rooms with no windows?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, accommodation-search-engines

I sometimes prefer rooms without window. How can I find hotels in a given area that rent rooms with no windows? Do some accommodation search engines have such a filter?

Comment: Why only sometimes?

Comment: In my experience that's quite rare and if it happens the hotels go out of their way to hide it since it's NOT what most customer want. Some hotel advertise it as a gimmick but I highly doubt it made it into a search engine. Not enough demand.

Comment: @matt freake I guess where it is noisy outside.

Comment: This simply doesn't exist in many countries due to building code considerations for lighting and energy efficiency. See e.g. [International Property Maintenance Code 402.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPMC2012/chapter-4-light-ventilation-and-occupancy-limitations).

Comment: @user71659 I'd be more concerned about fire safety.  However my 5 minutes of googling shows that it does exist in several locations - albeit the concensus was that typically it was in older buildings that had been converted to hotels.

Comment: I can't speak for why the OP sometimes prefers rooms without a window, but I prefer that if I'm travelling for work and expecting to be working overnight and sleeping during the day.  I know a few hotels in cities I regularly visit for work, and they're always very pleased to give me a room without a window if I ask – I get the impression no-one else likes them.  But I'm afraid I don't know how to find hotel with rooms without windows.  I don't think they're at all common.

Comment: @mattfreake depends on noise levels, time of the first meeting in the morning vs sunrise time, etc.

Comment: Not an answer because it's a specific chain, but EasyHotels offer windowless rooms as standard and charge more for rooms with windows.

Comment: @user71659 windowless rooms are actually more energy efficient. These regulations exist because of NIMBY concerns over poor people being able to stay in affluent areas, as you could cram a lot more people in windowless rooms.

Comment: If the concern is for light, most hotels I've been at have blackout curtains that block pretty much *all* light coming from outside.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen an explicit windowless room filter, and in many jurisdictions windowless rooms are against building code. But you can try your luck on Google Maps by searching for "windowless hotel", which finds reviews by people complaining about them!

One more place to look is the [Yotel](https://www.yotel.com/en) chain, which specializes in tiny rooms for short stays. Many -- but no means all -- of their rooms are windowless, particularly at their many "YotelAir" airport hotels.

And in Japan, virtually all capsule hotels are windowless, although the capsules are typically also doorless (there's a curtain instead) so they're not great if you want to isolate yourself completely.